# As tags [date] e [data] não deveriam ser sinônimas?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags-sinônimas

Pelo que é descrito no wiki de ambas as tags, [date](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/date/info) e [data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/data/info) são referentes a mesma coisa, mas uma tag é em inglês e a outra em português.

Comment: A tag "data" talvez nem devesse existir. Geralmente "date", assim como "datetime", costuma ter relação com o tipo, e por ser nome técnico não vejo razão em traduzir. Sobre outros assuntos ligados à manipulação de datas, se realmente for relevante para o problema (tipo diferenças de fuso horário, discontinuidades de tempo em certos calendários, _time drift_) talvez fosse necessária uma tag mais abrangente (não analisei as postagens com a tag `data` ainda, talvez ajude a visualizar melhor o problema)

Comment: É uma boa discussão, vejo motivo para juntar e pra manter separado, embora eu sei que separado estão usando errado (não é um argumento que deva ser decisivo).

Comment: existe uma funcionalidade de synonyms? Atualizei o tag "date" para ficar mais preciso o significado de informação.

Comment: Na minha opinião eu acho que não deveria existir a tag "date", já que estamos no SO-ptbr. "date" é "data" em inglês, e "data" em inglês não refere-se a "data" em português. Porém, concordo que fica complicado, já que na nossa área usamos muitas tags com nome em inglês sem traduzi-los. Já "datetime" poderia existir, que é um tipo de campo em bancos de dados (sem bem que "date" também é... enfim)...

Comment: Concordo com o @RodrigoTognin, se é SOpt, é Data e não Date, se considerar o Inglês, então Date para Data(tempo) e Data para Dados(informações), mas não creio que seria isso. Deve-se retirar a tag Date em minha opinião.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns meses depois que esta pergunta foi feita (mais precisamente em agosto/2019) eu sugeri o sinônimo na [respectiva página da tag data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/data/synonyms). E neste mesmo link pode-se ver que a sugestão foi aprovada (caso tenha curiosidade, as regras para aprovação estão na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) e também no [FAQ do Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/401803)).

Sendo assim, agora a tag [date](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) é sinônimo da tag [data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data).

<sup><sub>Só fiquei sabendo da aprovação do sinônimo porque hoje [ganhei a respectiva medalha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/72/synonymizer?userid=112052).</sub></sup>