# O Meta não deveria ser mais ágil?

Tags: debate, meta

Algumas perguntas no metas são para melhoria da comunidade, por exemplo:

- [Podemos remover a página “How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” (Como fazer perguntas no Beta Privado) da Central de Ajuda?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7730)

Todos concordam que sim, pode ser retirado, mas [a página continua lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) (último link da lista), isso faz uns 2 meses e meio

- [As tags date e data não deveriam ser sinônimas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7757)

Considerando os votos positivos diria que essa também foi aprovada, nos comentários há alguns comentários dizendo que uma ou outra não deveria existir, mas não teve muitos positivos. Essa é mais recente, faz 1 mês

- [Ambiguidade na descrição de medalha](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7769)

Aqui tudo bem que nada foi feito, afinal, ninguém postou alguma ideia de uma nova explicação. Mas nesses casos os moderadores não podem adicionar a tag [destaque](/questions/tagged/destaque) para tentar chamar mais a atenção da comunidade?

- [Desorganização nos nomes e tags desnecessárias relacionadas ao HTTP](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7788)

Essa outra pergunta é recente, menos de 2 semanas, mas parece estar indo para o mesmo caminho...

Não fui muito pra trás procurar perguntas como essas, mas certamente encontraria

Isso é pra ser assim mesmo (demorado)?

O que determina se uma ação já pode ser realizada (a comunidade em geral aceita a mudança/melhoria) ou deve ser discutida um pouco mais antes?

Comment: Um agravante disso é a baixa participação da comunidade no Meta. Quase podemos contar nos dedos os usuários que estão aqui.

Answer (score 13):

Sim, deveria. Mas nem sempre dá para ser.

Alguns casos todo mundo concorda significa que 3 pessoas concordaram. Se for algo sério, se for mais polêmico precisamos de mais validação para fazer algo. E a participação no meta está bem pequena. Então meio que os moderadores estão decidindo quase sozinhos, também com a ajuda de uns 3 que são quase moderadores informais. Não é bem a comunidade decidindo. Em algumas decisões isso importa pouco, mas outros precisa de mais peso.

Algumas coisas dão muito trabalho fazer, quem se habilita começar? Algumas coisas está meio decidido, mas falta alguém com bom conhecimento no assunto, no site, com bom senso, confirmar que não há qualquer problema específico e se tiver arrumar antes. Por exemplo, eu não sei se não tem algumas perguntas com as *tags* `data` e `date` onde a fusão não seria adequada e não vi alguém confiável garantindo isso. De qualquer forma só comentários não é aprovação de nada. Deveria ter uma resposta e as pessoas votarem nela pra dar mais legitimidade. Não quer dizer que não possa ter uma decisão, mas a falta de agilidade tem a ver com a falta de participação.

Tem coisa que não é tão importante tomar uma decisão. Ou como foi dito ainda não tem subsídio para tomar uma, ou pode ainda nem ser um pedido tão válido assim. Se nenhum moderador concordar, e depender deles, não será feito. Os moderadores são parte de uma etapa extra para algum pedido prosperar.

Algumas dependem da SE tomar a decisão final e fazer, não podemos nós moderadores fazer. Podemos fazer uma lista de coisas que queremos a intervenção deles e que nada foi feito para dar um alerta do que passou batido por eles. Quem começa? Claro que muitos casos eles só não disseram que não farão.